# CSS issue using slickgrid with Liferay

Tags: liferay, slickgrid, liferay-6

I'm trying to use `slickgrid` in my liferay 6.1 portal but something strange happens.

When I do

```
self.grid = new Slick.Grid('#list', self.dataView, columns, options);
```

The width of the grid expands to `3906.916748046875`.

I debugged my code and found that when this line is executed:

```
$topPanelScroller.hide();
```

The grid expands its width.

Outside Liferay Portal it is working ok.

Did it happened to anyone else? What can be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the issue.

In `layout.css` from liferay theme, there is:

```
.portlet-layout {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and it needs to be changed to:

```
.portlet-layout {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed; // this is changed from auto to fixed
    width: 100%;
}
```

may be useful to someone with the same problem ...